# AngularJS Loading templates from a REST Service

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, servicenow, angularjs-templates

I have an AngularJS application in which I am trying to load my view (templates) from a REST end point.  For some reason, the following code doesn't seem to be working.  I see the in the log, the message "getTemplates()", then nothing.  No XHR calls, no returns, nothing.  What am I missing? Why isn't the $http return being executed? Is there a better way to accomplish this?  -- Thank you!

```
.config(
  [
    '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider) {

            $stateProvider.state('applications',
                {
                    url: "/applications",
                    controller: 'ImageManager',
                    templateProvider: [ '$templateCache', function($templateCache) { return $templateCache.get("applications"); } ],
                    resolve: {                
                        'getTemplates' : [
                            '$log', '$rootScope', '$http', '$templateCache',
                            function( $log, $rootScope, $http, $templateCache ) {
                                $log.debug("getTemplates()");  /* I see this. */

                                return 
                                    $http
                                        .get('/api/now/table/x_cqt_cliqr_cliqr_templates?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_fields=title,html')
                                        .then(
                                            function( response ) {
                                               $log.debug("applications::resolve::getTemplates()");
                                               $log.debug(response);

                                               for(var idx=0; idx < response.data.result.length; idx++) {
                                                  $templateCache.put(response.data.result[idx].title.toLowerCase(), response.data.result[idx].html);
                                                }
                                            },

                                            function( response ) {
                                                $log.error("applications::resolve::getTemplates()");
                                                $log.error(response);
                                            }
                                        );
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: have you tried making this call to the REST API from API Explorer or another tool like cURL or Postman? Does it return results when the request is made outside of the browser?

Comment: It does.  I've tried other ways of calling it and they all work.  They just all seem to come in too late, after the template needs to be in the cache.  I'm dumbfounded as to why I'm not even seeing it make the call. In my full app, there are three similar functions chained together.  I can see all three being called, but none of them are executing the return.  The example is a simplified version of that.

Comment: why can't you just point `templateUrl` at the same endpoint?

Comment: It was a requirement of the platform Charlie.  It's running though a framework called Service-Now, not a standard site by any means.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not the answer was just remove the return and let the $http call execute.  I cannot explain why it was failing though. I would think it would evaluate the call still.